# Iterating through 2D heap array that is nested in a structure in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, malloc

I am new to C, pointers, and structures and I currently am working on a basic program where I need to iterate through a 2-D heap array that is an element of a structure. The code for the structure is below, which represents an `n x n` bookshelf where `n` is the element `size` and there will be n books in each row/column:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;           
    int **book_shelf;
} BookShelf;
```

Below is a separate function where I intend on iterating through the element `**book_shelf` in a BookShelf structure:

```
// Return a pointer to a full BookShelf struct
BookShelf *createBookShelf(int n) {
      BookShelf *bsptr = malloc(sizeof(BookShelf));
      bsptr -> size = n;
      // Code to iterate should go here
}
```

Where I am confused is how I can use the `*bsptr` pointer to access and iterate through the `int **book_shelf` element of a `BookShelf` struct. I am also unsure if I need to allocate memory for this element or if the line `BookShelf *bsptr = malloc(sizeof(BookShelf));` is already taking care of that. Any help/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can access the `book_shelf` member of the allocated object analogously to the `size` member: `bsptr->book_shelf`.  But you must understand that this is accessing a *pointer* of type `int **`.  Until you assign a valid pointer value to it, that member does not point to anything.  It does not necessarily need to point to dynamically allocated memory, but my guess would be that that is what you want. And no, no allocation for any such additional memory will have been made, because it's only the pointer that is part of your structure, not whatever it points to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the tip. I used a C visualizer online and figured it out with the additional allocation of the memory. I should be good now